# Error downloading apex:apex-jorje-ide:1.0-sfdc-187-SNAPSHOT-55042bfc2e

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, akka

I am using Scala 2.13.9 and SBT version 1.1.1 and I see this error when i run the `sbt run` command. I do not find this dependency anywhere. I have looked on MVN repositories as well but t could not find it.
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a publicly available dependency? If not there's no way we can help you. Also, it's a SNAPSHOT version, probably doesn't exist anymore: use fixed version instead.